# Howto get flags from enum value?

Tags: c#, enum-flags

Trying to get array of all possible flags from enum value, say 3 to array of {1, 2}.

I have an extension

```
internal static MyEnum[] GetFlags(this MyEnum modKey)
{            
    string[] splitStr = modKey.ToString().Split(new string[1] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    MyEnum[] flags = new MyEnum[splitStr.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitStr.Length; i++)
    {
        flags[i] = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), splitStr[i]);
    }
    return flags;
}
```

...but it seems a bit wasteful for the purpose. Could this be done more effectively?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply filter all possible values of the `MyEnum` to the ones in `modKey`:

```
internal static MyEnum[] GetFlags(this MyEnum modKey)
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
        .Cast<MyEnum>()
        .Where(v => modKey.HasFlag(v))
        .ToArray();
}
```

**Edit**

Based on the comment below, in case of combinations specified, the method should only return the combinations, not all flags set.

The solution is to loop through all flags set in the enum starting from the highest one. In each iteration, we have to add a flag to the result, and remove it from the iterated enum until it's empty:

```
internal static MyEnum[] GetFlags(this MyEnum modKey)
{
    List<MyEnum> result = new List<MyEnum>();

    while (modKey != 0)
    {
        var highestFlag = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
            .Cast<MyEnum>()
            .OrderByDescending(v => v)
            .FirstOrDefault(v => modKey.HasFlag(v));

        result.Add(highestFlag);
        modKey ^= highestFlag;
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Neither this or Gian Paolo's answer actually works if the enum has some of the combinations specified. For example, do this to Windows Forms CapsLock and you will get MButton, ShiftKey, Capital, Capital. I was only looking for to get the value of CapsLock (Capital).

Comment: @bwa Then `Keys.MButton | Keys.ShiftKey` would also return `{ Keys.CapsLock, Keys.Capital }`. Is that the behavior you expect?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, though splitting hair...I mean strings seems to be faster when tested with Keys. 10k iterations 49ms vs 1671ms.

Comment: This [Keys enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) is not the best example. It's got several issues. One might wonder why it's a *flagged* enum.

Answer (score 3):

assuming your MyEnum has a Flags Attribute, to test if a flag is set the (standard?) way is to perform a binary & between your value and the flag you want to test:
so something like this should work:

```
internal static MyEnum[] GetFlags(this MyEnum modKey)
{
    List<MyEnum> flags = new List<MyEnum>();
    foreach (var flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
    {
        if (modKey & flag == flag)
            flags.Add((MyEnum)flag);
    }
    return flags.ToArray(); 
}
```

if you use .Net 4 or later, you can use HasFlag

```
        if (modKey.HasFlag((MyEnum)flag))
            ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Both answers don't do what (I think) is asked: get the *elementary* values from an enum value, not any composed values. One example where this may be useful is when one enum value must be used in a `Contains` statement in LINQ to a SQL backend that doesn't support `HasFlag`.

For this purpose I first created a method that returns elementary flags from an enum type:

```cs
public static class EnumUtil
{
    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetFlags<TEnum>()
        where TEnum : Enum
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
            .Cast<TEnum>()
            .Where(v =>
            {
                var x = Convert.ToInt64(v); // because enums can be Int64
                return x != 0 && (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
                // Checks whether x is a power of 2
                // Example: when x = 16, the binary values are:
                // x:         10000
                // x-1:       01111
                // x & (x-1): 00000
            });
    }
}
```

And then a method that returns elementary flags from an enum value:

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetFlags<TEnum>(this TEnum enumValue)
        where TEnum : Enum
    {
        return GetFlags<TEnum>()
            .Where(ev => enumValue.HasFlag(ev));
    }
```

#### Usage

Taking this enum type:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum WeekDay
{
    Monday = 1 << 0,
    Tuesday = 1 << 1,
    Wednesday = 1 << 2,
    Thursday = 1 << 3,
    Friday = 1 << 4,
    Saturday = 1 << 5,
    Sunday = 1 << 6,

    BusinessDay = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday,
    WeekendDay = Saturday | Sunday,
    All = BusinessDay | WeekendDay
}
```

The statements (in Linqpad)...

```cs
string.Join(",", EnumUtil.GetFlags<WeekDay>()).Dump();

var t = WeekDay.Thursday | WeekDay.WeekendDay;
string.Join(",", t.GetFlags()).Dump();

t = WeekDay.All;
string.Join(",", t.GetFlags()).Dump();
```

...return this:

```
Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday
Thursday,Saturday,Sunday
Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday
```

Basic idea taken from [this answer to my question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/215346/7251).

Comment: I don't see an evidence in @xnp's OP that reflects that this was the intention, though clearly from his comment above, it was.  That said, this was exactly what _I_ needed, so thank you for posting this answer!